# Experimenting with Virtualization 

Tags: virtualization, google-chrome-os

I want to try Google OS. For that purpose I am planning to install virtualization software. I have the option to use VMWare Palyer or VirtualBox. I am absolute beginner, and even though I understand the concept of virtualization, never used it. Can you please suggest which of the two option (i.e. VMWare Player or VirtualBox) is easy option for beginner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Vmware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/index.html) is much easier to use as there are fewer controls, however it is only really designed to run VMs that already exist and not create them from scratch.

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) gives you a lot more options but it would be my choice between the two if you want to install from scratch.

Why do you say Google OS if you are talking about the desktop version? (I know it is out of the rumour stage, but I didn't know they had released anything). If you are talking about android on the other hand, if you [download the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/), they have an emulator that runs out the box and may be much simpler if you just want a play with it.

Comment: Thanks. The download as free virtual appliance of Chrome OS is available (http://sites.google.com/site/chromeoslinux/download). I plan to try out this version which requires VMWare Player or VirtualBox. Regards

Comment: Can't believe I missed this! thanks... already given +1 to your question, shame I can't do more!... well, +1 to your comment!

Comment: OHhhhhh, it's not made by Google.  Some dude just put Chrome OS on Suse: http://lifehacker.com/5369361/try-out-a-fan+made-chrome-os-linux-build?skyline=true&s=x.  Deliberately misleading, wish I could downvote his whole website.

Comment: Lol, that's more like it!

Comment: Totally installing that now.

Comment: Sorry about Chrome OS. It's not by Google. As usual did not read the fine print. Regards

Comment: I just tried it and it said *

Site Disabled

This site has been disabled for violations of our Terms of Service. If you feel this disabling was in error, please visit our contact page to let us know.*

Answer (score 10):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is dead simple, and it's free. Use it.

> VirtualBox is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization product for enterprise as well as home use. Not only is VirtualBox an extremely feature rich, high performance product for enterprise customers, it is also the only professional solution that is freely available as Open Source Software under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2. See "About VirtualBox" for an introduction.
>
> Presently, VirtualBox runs on Windows, Linux, Macintosh, and Solaris hosts and supports a large number of guest operating systems including but not limited to Windows (NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Server 2003, Vista, Windows 7), DOS/Windows 3.x, Linux (2.4 and 2.6), Solaris and OpenSolaris, OS/2, and OpenBSD.
>
> VirtualBox is being actively developed with frequent releases and has an ever growing list of features, supported guest operating systems and platforms it runs on. VirtualBox is a community effort backed by a dedicated company: everyone is encouraged to contribute while Oracle ensures the product always meets professional quality criteria.

Comment: +1 also no issues with unsigned drivers on x64 Windows that VMWare has/had.

Answer (score 5):

VirtualBox.

VMplayer is aimed solely at "playing" existing virtual machines. While there are hacks and interesting work-arounds to use Player to *create* VMs, I don't think that would be a great choice for a beginner...

Comment: ah see, I didn't realize you already had a pre-built image in mind...

Comment: Side Note: Current version of VMware Player now has the ability to create new VMs built-in. No more hacks or work-arounds necessary.

Answer (score 4):

VBox is free and does pretty much everything VMWare does. It's easily more capable than the free VMWare player.

If you have budget, I still prefer VMWare workstation for the flexibility of its disk snapshot mechanism. It's getting increasingly hard to justify the cost in the face of recent versions of VirtualBox though.